# Android Memory Ramp Up

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've been profiling my application in search of super small memory leaks. After analysing the profiler and respective logs, I've found out the following :

1. Every object I alloc is eventually dealloc(ed) by means of the GC which is good (internally called or if forced through the Android Studio's tools)
2. The 'toughest' objects and libraries are being properly managed so no leak is associated to it
3. My memory graph shows an evergrowing (and eventual downfall due to GC) Java allocation.

[image: Java ramp-up]

Even though the memory interval is well within the established limits (both inferior and superior) **can someone explain to me, detailed if possible, the reason for such considerable ramp-up on the memory trace for Java objects?**

**I am not interacting with the application by any means whatsoever. It is just standing still on a specific unchanging screen.**

Thank you in advance,